# JPA Integer conversion to String for MySQL query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

I have to write a JPA query to select data in a MySQL DB.

I have this part of code:

```
SELECT NEW com.fiat.sc.um.mdm.bean.Vendor
(e.fgpVndrNumber, e.companyName1, e.vndrCountry, 
e.city, e.postalCode, e.street, e.vatRegistrNum, 
e.vendorTypeDesc, e.companyName2, e.taxNumber2, 
e.taxNumber1, e.organizationCode) 
FROM ScVendor e
```

I want to add this where clause:

```
WHERE str(e.fgpVndrNumber) LIKE '%123%'
```

or

```
to_char(e.fgpVndrNumber) LIKE '%123%'
```

In few words, I have to convert an Integer in String.

But I obtain an error.

Suggestions?

**EDIT**

This is the complete Java code:

```
String selAndForm = "SELECT NEW com.fiat.sc.um.mdm.bean.Vendor(e.fgpVndrNumber, e.companyName1, e.vndrCountry,"
                + " e.city, e.postalCode, e.street, e.vatRegistrNum, e.vendorTypeDesc, e.companyName2, e.taxNumber2, "
                + "e.taxNumber1, e.organizationCode)  FROM ScVendor e ";

        String where = null;

        if (isNotNull(companyName)) {
            if (searchCriteriaCompName != null) {
                if (searchCriteriaCompName.equals("contains")) {
                    companyName = "%" + companyName + "%";
                }
                if (searchCriteriaCompName.equals("startWith")) {
                    companyName = companyName + "%";
                }
                if (searchCriteriaCompName.equals("endWith")) {
                    companyName = "%" + companyName;
                }
            }

            if (where == null) {
                where = "WHERE lower(e.companyName1) like '" + companyName.toLowerCase() + "'";
            } else {
                where = where + " AND lower(e.companyName1) like '" + companyName.toLowerCase() + "'";
            }
        }

        if (isNotNull(immediateParent)) {
            if (searchCriteriaParentCode != null) {
                if (searchCriteriaParentCode.equals("contains")) {
                    immediateParent = "%" + immediateParent + "%";
                }
                if (searchCriteriaParentCode.equals("startWith")) {
                    immediateParent = immediateParent + "%";
                }
                if (searchCriteriaParentCode.equals("endWith")) {
                    immediateParent = "%" + immediateParent;
                }
                if (searchCriteriaParentCode.equals("equals")) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }

            if (where == null) {
                where = "WHERE e.immediateParent LIKE '" + immediateParent + "'";
            } else {
                where = where + " AND e.immediateParent LIKE '" + immediateParent + "'";
            }
        }


        if (isNotNull(supplierCode)) {

            logger.debugT("supplierCode=" + supplierCode);

            if (searchCriteriaParentCode != null) {
                if (searchCriteriaSuppCode.equals("contains")) {
                    supplierCode = "%" + supplierCode + "%";
                }
                if (searchCriteriaSuppCode.equals("startWith")) {
                    supplierCode = supplierCode + "%";
                }
                if (searchCriteriaSuppCode.equals("endWith")) {
                    supplierCode = "%" + supplierCode;
                }
                if (searchCriteriaSuppCode.equals("equals")) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }

            if (where == null) {
                where = "WHERE e.fgpVndrNumber.toString() like '" + supplierCode + "'";
            } else {
                where = where + " AND e.fgpVndrNumber.toString() like '" + supplierCode + "'";
            }
        }


        StringBuffer SQL = new StringBuffer();

        SQL.append(selAndForm);
        SQL.append(where);
        SQL.append(" AND e.deletedAt IS NULL");

        logger.debugT(SQL.toString());
        Query query = eManager.createQuery(SQL.toString());
```

fgpVendorNumber is an Integer. I want to convert it in a String.

Comment: what error do you get? do you want to convert integer to string by sql or entity mapping ?

Comment: I added the complete code. I think now is more comprensible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No explicit casting is required to search part of the number.

Following query format should be working with no syntax or logical errors.

```
select ...
  from ...
 where e.fgpVndrNumber like '%123%'
```

Comment: No :( I already tried this. I obtain this error 
_java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: line 1: Argument 'e.fgpVndrNumber' is of wrong type (java.lang.Integer), must be (java.lang.String)_

Comment: Try `e.fgpVndrNumber.toString()`

Comment: What error are you facing on use of `to_char(...)`?

Comment: Or a `@Convert` annotation on `e.fgpVndrNumber` in the class referred by `e`

Comment: I found [this](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/2013/10/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter.html) but I should have a old jpa version...

Comment: This is a good solution.... but I have the necessity to convert this integer to code level, not in the entity... because the entity is used by others services...

Answer (score 0):

Use cast function in MySql Databases.

```
WHERE cast(e.fgpVndrNumber as varchar) LIKE '%123%'
```

**See also**

[MySql Cast](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Comment: This is not working... I tried also CONVERT(varchar(50), e.fgpVndrNumber) as fgpVndrNumberInt like '%123%'

Answer (score 0):

Trying to compare an Integer against a String in JPA JPQL would cause an error.
I was able to convert the Integer into a String that could be compared doing this:

`WHERE substring(xInteger, 0) like '%stringFilter%'`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use TRIM with my JPA query:

```
WHERE TRIM(e.fgpVndrNumber as varchar) LIKE '%123%'
```